# Analyse XML file with powershell script

Tags: xml, powershell, xpath, select-xml

I've got a xml log file. The file looks like this:

```xml
<Transaction name='0' id='1'>
    <Response>Warning</Response>
    <Statistic mode='Element'>
      <Information>0</Information>
      <Warning>0</Warning>
      <Error>0</Error>
    </Statistic>
    <Messages>
      <Message state='Warning'>Personal-Nr.: 12345, Tom Test</Message>
      <Message state='Warning'>This is a warning message 1</Message>
      <Message state='Warning'>This is a warning message 2</Message>
      <Message state='Warning'>This is a warning message 3</Message>
      <Message state='Warning'>This is a warning message 4</Message>
    </Messages>
</Transaction>
```

This pattern repeats about 900 times Sometimes with more or less Messages. Now I just want to get all the Transactions where the `<Response>Error</Response>` occurs.

So I made this code in Powershell:

```bash
## parsing xml file and opening inner node
Select-Xml -Path C:\Users\user\path\path\file.xml -XPath '/Paths/Task/Transaction' | ForEach-Object { $_.Node.InnerXML }

## looping through Response set with include="Error"
$_.Node.InnerXML | Where-Object Response -eq 'Error' | ForEach-Object { $_.Messages }
echo $_.Messages
```

But the only data I get is all of the transactions, no matter if the response is `Warning` or `Error`. Even further, it doesn't even matter if I only leave the `Select-Xml` line and delete the rest. The result is always the same. I always get ALL of the responses.

So my question is:
How do I get only get the transactions where the Response is `Error`?

Bonus question: Is there a possibility to just have the first message line of each `Error` transaction as a output? So that I have a list of all the `Personal-Nr` that were in an error transaction?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statements you've posted are completely independent at the moment - the first one outputs the textual encoding of all the transactions nodes, and the second and third ones simply *do nothing*, because `$_` no longer has a value assigned to it at that point.

To properly "connect" them, you'd have to either place the filtering logic inside the first `ForEach-Object` block, eg.:

```
Select-Xml ... |ForEach-Object {
  if($_.Node.Response -eq 'Error'){ $_.Messages }
}
```

... or store the output from each step in an interim variable, eg.:

```
$allTransactions = Select-Xml ... -XPath '//Transaction' 

$allTransactions |ForEach-Object {
  if($_.Node.Response -eq 'Error'){ $_.Messages }
}
```

I should point out that `ForEach-Object { if(...){ $_ } }` is a bit of an anti-pattern unless your code has more complicated side effects - the more idiomatic solution would be to invoke the `Where-Object` cmdlet to filter the output from `Select-Xml`:

```
$allTransactions |Where-Object {
  $_.Node.Response -eq 'Error'
} |ForEach-Object Messages
```

While these suggestions might solve your problem, I strongly recommend *not doing any of that* - XPath is **much more capable** than what you're currently using it for :)

---

> How do I get only get the transactions where the Response is "Error"?

I'd suggest simplifying your code by using a more *accurate* XPath expression with `Select-Xml` - one that looks for exactly what you want:

```
Select-Xml -Path C:\Users\user\path\path\file.xml -XPath '/Paths/Task/Transaction[Response = "Error"]'
```

> Is there a possibility to just have the first message line of each "Error" transaction as a output? So that I have a list of all the "Personal-Nr" that were in an error transaction?

Sure thing!

Once again the easiest way is to modify the XPath expression, this time to only resolve the *first* `<Message>` node under a `<Transaction>` fitting the criteria above:

```
# beware that index selectors in XPath start at 1, not 0
//Transaction[Response = "Warning"]/Messages/Message[1]
```

But that's not all! XPath has several useful functions - so we can go *one step deeper* and have `XPath` extract and decode the message text for us too!

```
//Transaction[Response = "Warning"]/Messages/Message[1]/text()
```

This will cause `Select-Xml` to return a node set consisting of `XmlText` instances which you can convert directly to strings to get the raw string content.

Putting it back together with `Select-Xml`, you end up with something like this:

```
$filePath = 'C:\Users\user\path\path\file.xml'
$xPath = '//Transaction[Response = "Warning"]/Messages/Message[1]/text()'
$messages = Select-Xml -Path $filePath -XPath $xPath |ForEach-Object ToString

$messages
```

Comment: Thank you very much for that detailed solution. That was exactly what I was looking for! The last code you posted worked like a charm.